# How estimate series by its own term in the Banch space?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a Bench space. Assume that $x_n \in X$ for all $n=0,1,....$ We may notice that $\|f\|\geq \|g\|-\|f-g\| $ for $f, g\in X.$

Put $y= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n.$
Notice that

$\|y\| \geq \|x_1\| - \|y-x_1\| \geq \|x_1\|- \|x_0\|- \|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x_n\|$.

Now (using the fact that $s-t\geq s$ if $t\geq 0$), we may obtain that

$$\|y\|\geq \|x_1\|.$$

> My question is: Where is the  flaw in this proof?

I think there is a flaw  in the proof. If so, under what conditions on $\|x_i\|$ we may conclude that $\|y\|\geq \|x_1\|$?

I think if we assume $\|x_1\|\geq \|x_0\|$  and $\|x_1\|\geq \|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x_n\|$ then we may conclude  that $\|y\|\geq \|x_1\|$. But I do not know how. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with norms of elements, the inequalities you are dealing with are about numbers and have little to do with Banach spaces nor norms.

Say $\|x_1\|=5$, $\|x_0\|=5$, $\|\sum_2^\infty x_n\|=0$. Then you want to conclude, from 
$$
\|y\|\geq0=5-5-0=\|x_1\|-\|x_0\|-\left\|\sum_2^\infty x_n\right\|,
$$
that $\|y\|\geq5$. For instance take $x_0=5$, $x_1=-5$, $x_2=x_3=\cdots=0$.